# Logs are not recorded when using external log configuration

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

I have Spring MVC web application deployed on tomcat. (Not Spring Boot)
I want to use external log file to have access to it during runtime. Log4j2 library.
`log4j.configurationFile` parameter is used to enable external configuration.
Also I have external `.yaml` file that stored on file system of server.

The behaviour now:
If i put the same log4j2.xml to my resources, everything works fine.
With external log4j2 config, the `.log` file is created after application is started, and it has some logs about application initialization. But nothing is recorded further.
Also if I create additional appender on runtime - file is not created. So automatic reconfiguration does not work as well.

After some searches I came to this configuration for applying external `.yaml`:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyConfig {

    public static final String ENV_HOME_VARIABLE = "APP_HOME";
    public static final String MAIN_CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "app-config.yaml";

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties(@Autowired ConfigurableEnvironment conf) throws MalformedURLException {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        String configPath = "file:" + System.getenv(ENV_HOME_VARIABLE) + "/" + MAIN_CONFIG_FILE_NAME;

        yaml.setResources(new UrlResource(configPath));
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());
        Map map = conf.getSystemProperties();
        yaml.getObject().forEach((key, value) -> {
            map.put(key, value);
        });
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

Also here is `log4j.configurationFile` initialization in `app-config.yaml`:

```
log4j:
 configurationFile: file:/home/user/appHome/app-log4j2.xml
```

And app-log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorinterval="30" status="WARN" >

    <Appenders>
        <!-- Rolling File Appender -->
        <RollingFile name="rollingFileApplication" bufferSize="0" bufferedIO="false" append="true">
           <FileName>/home/user/appHome/log/app.log</FileName>
           <FilePattern>/home/user/appHome/log/archive/app%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</FilePattern>
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>

            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="/home/user/appHome/log/archive/" maxDepth="1">
                    <IfAll>
                        <IfFileName glob="app_*.log*" />
                        <IfLastModified age="7d" />
                    </IfAll>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="rollingFileApplication" level="TRACE"/>
        </Root>

        <Logger name="ua" additivity="true" level="TRACE">
            <appender-ref ref="rollingFileApplication"/>
        </Logger>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Records in `app.log` after start:

```
2022-07-28 12:53:39 PM [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2022-07-28 12:53:40 PM [localhost-startStop-1] TRACE org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Found Equinox FileLocator for OSGi bundle URL resolution
2022-07-28 12:54:10 PM [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2022-07-28 12:54:10 PM [localhost-startStop-1] TRACE org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Found Equinox FileLocator for OSGi bundle URL resolution
2022-07-28 12:54:25 PM [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2022-07-28 12:54:25 PM [localhost-startStop-1] TRACE org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Found Equinox FileLocator for OSGi bundle URL resolution
```

So the question is, why do you think it`s not working and how to make it work).
Ready to provide any additional information.
Will appreciate any suggestions or remarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I found a solution.
Looks more like workaround, but it still works:

```
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties(@Autowired ConfigurableEnvironment conf) throws MalformedURLException {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        String configPath = "file:" + System.getenv(ENV_HOME_VARIABLE) + "/" + MAIN_CONFIG_FILE_NAME;

        yaml.setResources(new UrlResource(configPath));
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());
        Map map = conf.getSystemProperties();
        yaml.getObject().forEach((key, value) -> {
            map.put(key, value);
        });

   // solution
        LoggerContext context = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        File file = new File(System.getenv(ENV_HOME_VARIABLE) + "/app-log4j2.xml");

        // this will force a reconfiguration
        context.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
   // solution

        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
```